# Chrome CSS background-image problems with animation

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Here is the link to code https://jsfiddle.net/pk7zetdu/6/

```
$('.img_cont').addClass('rollIn');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.img_cont').removeClass('rollIn').addClass('rollOut');
  }, 3000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#img_img').attr('src', 'http://www.hercampus.com/sites/default/files/2013/02/27/topic-1350661050.jpg');
    $('.img_co....
```

Try to open it with latest stable chrome for windows.

First when it loads, you can see the slide (div) rolling in and rolling out, than image SRC is changed and div rolls in for the second time with new bg (maybe with a small img loading delay). All fine!

Then please press RUN button in fiddle and watch again. You now can see the slide (div) rolling in and rolling out, than image SRC is changed, but it rolls in with previous image in bg and changes it right after the animation is complete.

I can ensure you this has nothing to do with Image loading or fiddle it self, because it's a big problem in my real project. -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; on IMG solves the issue, but introduces to other problems in more serious examples :(.

Any ideas?

================ UPDATE

When I change .rollOut opacity to something not zero (https://jsfiddle.net/pk7zetdu/8/), the problem is gone. Seems that when opacity of img parent is 0, chrome does not adjust new SRC, and has problems to adjust it while in animation.

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: Could it be a coincidence with how long it takes for the image to load? try and make sure the images are loaded before you do the timeouts.

Comment: Don't think so. See update https://jsfiddle.net/pk7zetdu/6/ . Loading should not be the issue. 3 second is good to load :)

Comment: After this small test https://jsfiddle.net/pk7zetdu/8/ I start to suspect, that when opacity is 0, the image is not being loaded and some-have wrongly taken from cache while animating.

Answer (score 2):

Your second image has a shadow around all its sides. You can see that if you open the image in a tab(you will see that the image has some gap from top and left). 
So your second image doesnt load with the first image in background. Its just the second image that has the white gap around it.

Changing the images will do the trick. Check this fiddle with different images. -  https://jsfiddle.net/pk7zetdu/11/

As for the second image not rolling out after 3 seconds, you can change the `setTimeout` to `setInterval`

Comment: Same bug bro in your example. You didn't understand my issue, or you can't reproduce. Read the comment of Beep, he was the nearest.

Comment: Are you talking about the gap between the rolling out of 1st image and rolling in of 2nd one?

Comment: When the div starts to roll in for the second time, old background is shown. And changed only after animation is ended.

Answer (score 0):

This was Chrome March built bug. It's fixed in newest version. Anyway (if you care about march version) a quick fix is to set Opacity to something like 0.0001 instead of 0, when fading out. There is no good solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11896144)